# Mysql & Php Database connection error

Tags: php, mysql

When ever I use php to connect to my database I get a sudden error saying "database connection failed" is there anyway to fix this its for a login and register screen. Thanks to anyone who help...

```
<?php
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root','','test');
if (!$connection){
    die("Database Connection Failed" . mysqli_error($connection));
}
$select_db = mysqli_select_db($connection, 'test');
if (!$select_db){
    die("Database Selection Failed" . mysqli_error($connection));
}


<?php
    //
    require('database.php');
    $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root','','test');
    // If the values are posted, insert them into the database.
    if (isset($_POST['Register'])){
        $username = $_POST['username'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $query = "INSERT INTO `user` (username, email, password) VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$password')";
         //echo $query;
        $result=mysqli_query($connection,$query);
        if($result){
            $smsg = "User Created Successfully.";
        }else{
            $fmsg ="User Registration Failed";
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: `$select_db = mysqli_select_db($connection, 'test');
if (!$select_db)` that isn't needed, you're using all 4 arguments in the first line. Why are you also trying to reconnect after?

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text**.

Answer (score -1):

Connection to a database with php requires 4 parameters (host, data base user, password, data base name, passwd), it's better nowadays to use db object instead of procedural "old" behaviour:

```
function connection(){
    try{
        //host, user, passwd, DB name)
        $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", $dbUser, $passwd, $dbName);
        if (!$mysqli->set_charset("utf8")) $msg = "error charset mySQLi"; else $msg = "Set UTF-8 ok";
        return $mysqli;
    }
    catch (Exception $mysqlin){
        echo "Error stablishing connection with database ".$mysqlin->getMessage();  
    }
}
```

then you can connect easily as follows:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users;";
        if(!$result = connection()->query($sql)) echo "db query error"; else "query ok";
        $rs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
//do whatever and, to get next line of results:
if($rs!=''){
    $rs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
}
```

So you get a row of the results on $rs[] array.

**EDIT:** You'll need to apply security, this is a simple connection without regarding on it. Check mysqli bind params on php official webpage for it:
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Hope it helps